# How to get list of traits which a trait is composed of

Tags: php

**Question:** Is there a way to get a list of the traits which a trait is composed of? For reference, I'm refering to [traits composed from traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.composition).

**Scenario:** I have classes for models `User`, `Account` and `Lead`. I have  traits called `People`, `Importable`, `Exportable`, `Validatable`, `ImplicitAttributable`, `Auditable`, `Listable`, `Permitable`, `Searchable`, `Encryptable`, `Hashable`, `Currentable`, `Relatable` and `Triggerable`. All 3 classes implement the `People` trait.

The trait called `People` is composed of `Auditable`, `Listable`, `Permitable`, `Searchable`, `Encryptable`, `Hashable`, `Currentable`, `Relatable` and `Triggerable`.

I am trying to filter my classes by traits. However, when I try to filter the by the trait `Searchable`, which isn't specifically defined on one of the models (instead it's part of the composed trait `People`), I get no results.

**Current Methods Used:**

I've tried to use PHP's [class_uses](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-uses.php) and the following function:

```
function getTraitsForClass($class)
{
    return array_keys((new \ReflectionClass($class))->getTraits());
}
```

to generate the list of traits to filter by. I get the `People` trait in the list, but I don't get the `Searchable` trait.

**Additional Information:**

I'm building my application using Laravel 5.7 with PHP 7.1.23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `ReflectionClass` can also be used on Traits. So I modified my function to:

```
function getTraitsForClass($something)
{
    $traits = array_keys((new \ReflectionClass($something))->getTraits());
    foreach ($traits as $trait) {
        $traits = array_merge($traits, getTraitsForClass($trait));
    }
    $traits = array_unique($traits);
    return $traits;
}
```

And I was able to get the full list of traits.